# Use an array instead-react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to bring this firebase data but the method I do not allow to show it

Which causes it to show an error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {index, text}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

The firebase database structure :

[image]

Code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

 this.state = {
  ensayo:[],
  };
 }

 componentDidMount() {

  firebase
  .database()
  .ref("medidasAgregadas/")
  .on("child_added", (data) => {
    var datos = data.val();
    //alert(JSON.stringify(datos));
    var usuariosTemp2 = this.state.ensayo;
    datos.key = data.key;
    usuariosTemp2.push(datos);
    this.setState({ ensayo: usuariosTemp2 });
  });

}

render(){
return(
 <View>
 {this.state.ensayo.map((user) => (

 <Text>{user.info}</Text>

  ))}  
  </View>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `<Text>{user.info}</Text>` is causing an error because `user.info` is an array of objects with keys {index, text}, as can be seen in that Firebase screenshot.

Replace it with

```
user.info.map(item => <Text>index:{item.index}, text:{item.text}</Text>)
```

Comment: Try <Text>index:{user.info[0].index}, text:{user.info[0].text}</Text>?

Or to be sure, if you `console.log(this.state.ensayo)` and put that output in your question I'd be able to help more

Comment: has worked! using {user.info[0]. index}, text:{user.info[0]. text},when you have more,for example 0 and 1 what should you do?

Comment: You can add another map over that array - I;ve updated my answer to match